# Is there a reason i should not create a git repo in OneDrive?

Tags: git, onedrive

I am fairly new to the developer world and i just wanted to know if there is a good reason i should not have a git/github repo on a OneDrive folder?

I'm not in need of the syncing of OneDrive, it's just were i have a lot of my other work related things.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735148/git-repository-in-onedrive-synced-folder (it's a bit out of date) also I have a lot of tales about OneDrive not being able to handle it. All my repo's are on my local drive.

Comment: Thanks! I talked to a senior in my new company (known to be the "git" guy in the company) and he said that for a personal project it should be fine, as long as i don't rely on the syncing of OD.